# Manual email of payment pledges expired

Tags: wordpress, pledges

I had to record the payment pledges in this way:
€ 80.00 to August 10 (but may change depending on the individual)
€ 90.00 to 15 September(but may change depending on the individual)
€ 100.00 to December 01(but may change depending on the individual)
I created the payment commitments and then I changed the dates.
Now I have to warn all those who have not paid by September 15 with a mail automatically inserting the amount they have to pay.
How can I do? There is a token pledges?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Why are you moving dates and changing the amount paid and stating that it might change. Probably a bit more context on what and why might help in answerring your question

Comment: I have to manage the annual subscriptions of a basketball team.
Payments are divided into three:
August
September
December
I moving dates because the payments are 10 august, 15 September and 01 December.
I'd like to send a reminder to those who did not pay the installment of September

Comment: What you probably could use is the contribution status. You keep the status on pending and the date on the first date you expected the payment come in. Then when a payment comes in you set the status to complete. You could then search on contribution with status pending in a certain period.

Comment: Ok and how do I send an email to all the contacts that have not paid and the amount they have to pay? Not exist a contribution tokens.

Comment: E-mail is easy search for all contacts with a contribution with status pending. The token for amount to pay is not yet in CiviCRM. Not sure wether you have programming skills or not but it is easy to develop an extension which would contain such a token
How many people do you have to send a reminder too? If it is just a few you could just checkout the payment manually.

Comment: Thanks. 
From where can i start to create an extension?

Comment: The wiki contains usefull information: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+an+Extension you need to implement the hook token (http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_tokens) and the hook tokenValues (http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_tokenValues)